# Angular JS $location.path(...) not firing route controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to update the path on form submit using

```
$location.path('/search');
```

But it isn't triggering the route registered to `'/search'` I've tried with a trailing slash too. Nothing, I've also tried `$scope.$apply` but I just get the `$apply already in progress` error so there's definitely a scope.

Why wouldn't this call the controller registered to the route or load the `templateUrl` registered to it.

#### Router

```
App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
                "controller"  : "HomeController",
                "templateUrl" : "templates/home.html"
        })
        .when("/search", {
                "controller"  : "SearchResultsController",
                "templateUrl" : "templates/search-results.html"
        })
        .when("/search/:location", {
                "controller"  : "SearchLocationController",
                "templateUrl" : "templates/search-results.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
                "redirect" : "/"
        });
});
```

#### Form `ng-submit` callback

```
$scope.doSearchRequest = function (event, params) {
    // Prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();
    $scope.data = params;

    $location.path('/search/');
};
```

**edit**

Adding this

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
           $console.log('$routeChangeStart', arguments);
        });
```

Just before the `$location.path` call shows that the route doesn't start to change. Is this a bug in `Angular 1.2.5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out I actually needed to have an `ng-view` somewhere on the page for the whole system to work.

Seems a bit screwy but it works.

Comment: can you leverage your answer deeply, you mean you didn't include ng-view before? Or you just placed it in root? Because i have ng-view, but when route starts from 1 and goes to 2, and then go back to 1, controller either view doesn't load