# Controller not loading up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following `Index.html` file (I put `div` with `ng-view` as well):

```
<ul ng-controller="myController">    
    <li>
        <a href="#/doit">Do it!</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

routes config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/doit', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/doit.html'
        controller: 'myController'

    });

$routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'index.html'
    });
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {

        $scope.name = "name";
        alert($scope.name);
        $location.path("/");    

    }]);
```

The weird thig is that after I click on the `Do it!` link, it goes to `http://localhost:3000/#/doit.html` (the code of `myController` executes after the click, I see the alert pop-up), and then I go back to `http://localhost:3000/#/index.html` (this is what I want, I put `$location.path("/")` in the controller.

However, this time, for some reason, the controller code **doesn't** execute. It only runs after I refresh the page, even though it is assigned to the unordered list. Could anyone help please?

Comment: it does not work when going back via browser's back button?

Comment: Well, I can't go back because it once I land on doit.html I get redirected to index.html. It has probably something to do with $location.path("/"). Docs say it changes the URL in the browser (however, once Angular notices the change in URL bar, it looks in the routing rules and redirects me to index.html). The problem is that controller code doesn't run after index.html is loaded. ( it should, I have ng-controller directive there, right?)

Comment: and when does the error appear? i dont get it

Comment: Ok, step by step: I'm on index.html. Alert popup appears (it's in the controller - `alert($scope.name);`) Next, I click `<a href="#/doit">Do it!</a>`. Again, alert popup appears. It immediately redirects me to `index.html` (because of `$location.path("/")`), and this time nothing happens (no alert window with "name"), even though this alert window should appear (it's in the controller). Conclusion - the controller isn't loaded this time... for some reason.

Comment: i think it is because its already loaded - does it appear when you click on "do it" AFTER reloading?

Comment: I mean the line `alert(...)` in the controller doesn't execute. How can I force it to execute again?

Comment: this is what i was asking - does the alert appear by clicking on the link AFTER that reload?

Comment: It should appear immediately after I'm redirected back to that page by `$location.path("/"); `. Not clicks should be necessary. But yes, it does appear again after I click the link (but it runs in the `doit`'s myController, not `index`'s.) I would like the window to appear before and after I click the link.

Comment: you only posted 1 controller here

Comment: is this helpful: http://plnkr.co/edit/DVFG8T?p=preview ?

Comment: Yes, I posted 1 controller, because I use one controller for both.

Comment: Have you checked out this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606833/angular-js-location-path-not-firing-route-controller which suggests the addition of 'ng-view'. If you've already tried that, maybe take a look at this - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2770-route-must-be-injected-in-order-to-enable-the-routechangesuccess-event-in-angularjs.htm - inject '$route' into your controller (no need to use it) and probably listen for '$routeChangeSuccess' and see if you are hitting the listener on both cases -https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L193

Comment: what about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413760/reinitialize-an-angular-js-controller

Answer (score 0):

Your routes config should be something like:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/index.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
  }).
  when('/doit', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/doit.html',
    controller: 'myController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

and you do not need to specify controller name at two places i.e. in the partial and in your route config, specifying at the config level should be sufficient.

The `doit` view should be the one which is loaded in the ng-view tag as it is a state of your application.